# jQuery .css not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

I have a webpage with tabs, however I want some tabs to be hidden by default and shown when a login has been completed (on a successful login a function will be run in js, however I can't seem to show the tab from this function).

I have tried several methods, such as:
- tab hidden by default (with "display:none" in html), and using .css("display","inline-block"); to show it.
- tab hidden in a document load with .css("display","none"); and shown later with .css("display","inline-block");
- tab hidden in a document load with .hide(); and shown with .show();

However none of them work, the tab always shows. This is the part of the code which relates to this:

Document load method:

```
$(window).load(
  function() {
    $("addEventTab").css("display","none");
    $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
  }
}
```

login success function:

```
if (parseInt(response.substr(7,1)) >= 5) {
  $("addEventTab").css("display" , "inline-block");
  alert("appearing");
}
```

html code for the tab:

```
<li role="presentation"  id="addEventTab">
  <a href="#eventAdd" aria-controls="eventAdd" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
    <i class="fa fa-plus fa-1x">Add An Event</i>
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: missgin `#` in `$("addEventTab").css("display","none");` - Should be `$("#addEventTab").css("display","none");` since `addEventTab` is the `id` of the element - http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

Comment: Also can use `.hide()` instead of `.css('display', 'none')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `#` i.e. id selector of `addEventTab`:

```
$("#addEventTab").css("display","none");
```